# Statistics of the site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way to visualize the time-dependent statistics of our site, like how the requirements for coming out of beta changed so far? The small box to the right (Site Stats) and the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica) stats give only snapshots, though it would be nice to see the trends in a more straightforward way. Are we progressing or declining? For me, it seems like there is a slowdown in most of the statistics, though I can't tell whether the pace we attract new users is increasing or not. (A related question should be: if there is a decrease, what can we do about it?)

Comment: Indeed, it looks like we're slowing down a little. It might be good if everyone would use the means they have (Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, newsgroups, blogs, homepages etc.) to push up traffic a bit.

Comment: This is very much worth an Area51 feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been noting down the Area 51 statistics each day, and every week or so I post the resulting graphs in the chat room.

It is also possible to use the StackExchange API to get a lot of similar information. The raw data can be loaded into Mathematica in JSON form and processed.

I'm a bit busy right now, but since I was unable to solve a related Mathematica question, I will post a question on the main site that reveals how to do it at some stage (when I have time).

Comment: That would be nice, thanks in advance.

Comment: @IstvánZachar - I have posted a question on the main site that reveals how I get the data out of the StackExchange API.

Answer (score 3):

1. Have you seen the graphs that Verbeia posts in Chat from time to time?
2. As I moderator I have access to various site statistics, but I am required not to share specifics.  If you have general trend questions I believe I am allowed to answer those.

Comment: A general trend question, hmm? Quo vadimus...?

Comment: Since general trend questions are okay, I'm really curious, is the visit count still dropping slowly, is it steady, or is it increasing?  What about the page load count?  The median on the A51 stats page is not too informative, but it has reached 800 for the first time today.

Comment: @Szabolcs "Number of Visits" is slowing increasing, but roughly level since the second week of February.  "Total Page Views" dropped slightly from the mid-January to mid-February level in late February, then dropped a little more in early March.  Is is currently at the late-February level.  Over all "Total Page Views" (with smoothing) has been +/- 16% from the start -- quite level.

Answer (score 3):

CHM has provided code for scraping Area 51 pages and comparing across all betas in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3397/8). This is different from what I am doing, which is to track just our site through time.

Comment: I'm going to update the charts from time to time, to make them clearer and with more recent data.